# Why does the onclick fire next function not assigned to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, dom-events

Why clicking the button fires the alert? It is assigned to the paragraph, not button.
HTML:

```
<button onclick="foo()">Click me</button>
<p id="hidden" style="display:none"> I was hidden </p>
```

Javascript:

```
function foo(){
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("hidden").onclick = innnerClick(); 
}
function innnerClick(){
    alert("Ouch! That hurt!")
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because of this line:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------vv
document.getElementById("hidden").onclick = innnerClick();
```

Here you call the `innnerClick` function immediately.

Just remove `()` after to pass the reference to a function instead of calling it, i.e.

```
document.getElementById("hidden").onclick = innnerClick;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since, you need to add the reference of the function like this:

```
function foo(){
    document.getElementById("hidden").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("hidden").onclick = innnerClick; 
}
```

not directly calling it.

[`Fiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/FmP3C/)

In jQuery, we can reproduce the same issue like:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('#hidden').show();
    $('#hidden').click(innnerClick());  <-- see the function with () here
});
```

[`Fiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/8aJLh/)

The issue is same here, we just need to pass the function reference to click handler here like:-

```
$('#hidden').click(innnerClick);
```

[`Fiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/8aJLh/1/)